# How to split on every line using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
cover.jpg|http://domain2.com
insert.jpg|http://domain46.com
01.jpg|http://domain2g.com
```

I want to split by this character | on each line and get the first splitted string for each line so the final result should look like this:

```
cover.jpg
insert.jpg
01.jpg
```

This is my code and I can't get it to work for every line

```js
var s = 'cover.jpg|http://domain2.com\ninsert.jpg|http://domain46.com\n01.jpg|http://domain2g.com';
var fields = s.split('|');
alert(fields[0])
```

Comment: `s.split(/[\n|]/).filter((function(x, n) { return !(n%2);})).join('\n');` should do it

Comment: simply split by new line then for each row split by `|`. `var fields = s.split('\n');
fields.forEach(function(field){alert(field.split('|')[0]);})`

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi, can you explain what `x` and `n` are?

Comment: x is each item, n is it's ordinal position

Comment: Why is the downvote? At least he is showing his efforts or tell the reason to downvote so that he can correct his mistakes. You downvoted because you don't know the answer or is it too simple to answer.

Comment: @Lekhnath can't speak for the down voters, but I've never heard of anyone down voting because they don't know the answer (a bizarre yet often repeated claim, the opposite would make much more sense), or because it is too simple. Simple problems may be a sign of lack of research however, which I could see being applicable to this question. Further reading: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

You need to split by new line as well.

```js
var s = 'cover.jpg|http://domain2.com\ninsert.jpg|http://domain46.com\n01.jpg|http://domain2g.com';

s.split('\n').forEach(function(line){
  var fields = line.split('|');
  console.log(fields[0])
})
```

Comment: There is one line not multiple lines

Comment: @GM.Akbar there are multiple lines if you look closely. :)

Comment: Oh! sorry I saw that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the map function available to you, you can achieve this by splitting on the new line character, then splitting each line on the pipe character and getting the first item in the resulting array.

```js
var s = 'cover.jpg|http://domain2.com\ninsert.jpg|http://domain46.com\n01.jpg|http://domain2g.com';
var fields = s.split('\n').map(function(line){ return line.split('|')[0];});
console.log(fields);
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=map

Answer (score 1):

First split each row by using the regext `/\n/g` which will do a global split for the `\n` (new line) occurances.

Next loop each occurance of the fields (lines) and extract the file names by executing the regex `/\|/`. This regex splits by the `|` character (but only captures the first instance).

```js
var s = 'cover.jpg|http://domain2.com\ninsert.jpg|http://domain46.com\n01.jpg|http://domain2g.com';
   var fields = s.split(/\n/g);
   var fileNames = [];
   for(var i = 0;i<fields.length;i++){
 fileNames.push(fields[i].split(/\|/g)[0]);
   }
   alert(fileNames);
```

Comment: I don't want commas in the final result. How do I display them each in a new line?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
var array1 = s.split('\n');

var array2 = array1[0].split('|');
var array3 = array1[1].split('|');
var array4 = array1[2].split('|');

alert(array2[0]+"\n"+array3[0]+"\n"+array4[0]);
```

First split based on `'\n'` and then split based on `'|'`